# Программно нажать кнопку

Tags: javascript, android, веб-программирование

Имеется сайт с кнопкой, которая описана следующим образом:

```
div data-v-d71b5910="" data-v-403cbba6="" data-delimeter-preset="black" data- 
arrow-preset="black" data-icon-preset="black" class="buttonjoin" 
style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Нужно сделать `android` приложение, которое будет заходить на сайт и само нажимать на кнопку, интересует как реализовать нажатие этой кнопки. Cпасибо.

Comment: Взгляните в сторону Selenium

Comment: @Влад Селениум бегает под андроидом?